# scala interpreter error

Tags: scala, sbaz, scalacl

I did

```
  sudo sbaz update
  sudo sbaz install scalacl
  scala
```

gave me this error

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/LinearSeqOptimized
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
 at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
 at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1657)
 at scala.tools.nsc.plugins.Plugin$.instantiate(Plugin.scala:149)
 at scala.tools.nsc.plugins.Plugins$$anonfun$loadRoughPluginsList$1.apply(Plugins.scala:29)
 at scala.tools.nsc.plugins.Plugins$$anonfun$loadRoughPluginsList$1.apply(Plugins.scala:28)
 at scala.List.map(List.scala:812)
 at scala.tools.nsc.plugins.Plugins$class.loadRoughPluginsList(Plugins.scala:28)
 at scala.tools.nsc.Global.loadRoughPluginsList(Global.scala:34)
```

How do I fix this? Can I do a cleanup, because I didn't have this error before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What Scala version do you use? `Scalacl` is only compatible with 2.8.x (`LinearSeqOptimized` from your error message has also been introduced since 2.8)

Comment: I have 2.7.7.final. Thanks that explains it.